# keep the integers and remove the rest from list using regex

Tags: python

just keep the integers and remove the rest using regex here:

```
our_list = ["2121","eew3232", "32d-3", "(32"]
res = list(our_list.findall(r'[a-z],[,-', our_list))
```

Comment: Why regex? This is easier without.

Comment: Depends on on which level everything else should be sorted out: all list elements which are not pure integers or every character in each list element which is not an integer...?

Comment: Using `\D` would remove the hassle of having to use sets of everything that isn't a digit.

Comment: `[v for v in our_list if v.isdigit()]` I guess...

Comment: What exactly is your expected result in `res`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[''.join(j for j in i if j.isdigit()) for i in our_list]
#['2121', '3232', '323', '32']
```

And with regex:

```
[re.sub('[^0-9]','', i) for i in our_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

A big fan of regular expressions here, but this can easily be done without:

```
our_list = ["2121","eew3232", "32d-3", "(32"]
new_lst = [item for item in our_list if item.isdigit()]
print(new_lst)
# ['2121']
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/GuAMrj).

Comment: I think he means remove everything that isn't an integer from the other values in the list.

Comment: @Corsaka: You might be right but the question is a bit unclear to me.